# How to effciently decompress then recompress data with slight modifications

Tags: compression

Is there a library/compression format that allows you to, as you are decompressing data, retain information about the decompression so that when you need to recompress it later, it's faster?

I have `big_blob.z` that only requires a slight modification:
So what I am doing is decompressing `big_blob.z` into `big_blob`, modifying it slightly and then recompressing it back into `big_blob.z`

Most of the data will just be recompressed without any modifications.

My problem is that there is a lot of work that goes into compressing data and that work has already been done, is there a way to "help" the compressor by pre-seeding it's dictionary with information from the decompressor?

```
 ┌────────┐  ┌─────────────────────────────┐  ┌──────────┐
 │ DECOMP ├──► SLIGHT MODIFY / PASSTHROUGH ├──► COMPRESS │
 └──────┬─┘  └─────────────────────────────┘  └─▲────────┘
        │                                       │
        └───────────────────────────────────────┘
                    COMPRESSION INFO
```

This is mainly for 'heavy" compression algorithms like `LZMA` or `ZSTD`. If it was a "fast" algorithm like `gzip-1` or `LZ4` the recompression speed wouldn't be a big issue.

I know `ZSTD` has the capability to create a dictionary from training data that makes compression much, much faster, but I don't know if you can stream an incomplete dictionary into the compressor, or if it can decompress AND create a dictionary at the same time.

It doesn't need to be perfect, as long as it can "help" with the compression, I'll be happy.

---

Or, am I fundamentally misunderstanding how compression works?
Is there no information available in the decompressing of data that could help you to recompress it faster?

Comment: Technically, it is possible to make the compression of the modified block faster, but you have to get your hand dirty by reimplementing your specific decompression/recompression algorithm which save the structure of the compressed data so to then use it in the recompression part as an hint. IDK how big will be the speed up but it might be significant for algorithms like LZMA. However, this only works for the part of the input *before* the modification. After that, things become more complex and you may need to use the standard compression method.

Comment: Reimplementing such decompression/recompression algorithm is complex and tedious, and the final naive implementation is likely to be slower than the optimized standard implementation. Thus, it is certainly simpler and faster just to save a compressed patch. The patch will be small since it is supposed to be a "slight modify". However, this assumes tools/peoples reading the output file are aware of this patch.

Comment: I guess it would depend on how the compressor stores and accesses it's dictionary and how expensive it would be to update it in real time.